# How to add data to an already existing item in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, insert, insert-update, database

So i have a collection called 'users'. Where it lists a list of users and profile info.They are all stored inside mongodb. I want to add the option where they can add more pictures to their profile.For example I just want to add an extra "4":"newpicture.png" to "Documents" in the item inside the collection. How do I add a subsection to this item without having to rewrite all the data?

Eample of current data

```
{
  "name": "Oran",
  "username": "Oran.Hammes",
  "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brandonflatsoda/128.jpg",
  "email": "Oran.Hammes.Lubowitz@hotmail.com",
  "dob": "1953-03-21T17:40:17.020Z",
  "phone": "364-846-1607",
  "address": {
    "street": "Schultz Stream",
    "suite": "Suite 618",
    "city": "North Muriel mouth",
    "zipcode": "06447-1081",
    "geo": {
      "lat": "57.1844",
      "lng": "-56.8890"
    }
  },
  "website": "misty.net",
  "company": {
    "name": "Hettinger, Reilly and Stracke",
    "catchPhrase": "Multi-tiered system-worthy database",
    "bs": "best-of-breed evolve e-markets"
  },
  "Documents":{
    "1":"image.png",
    "2":"Test.jpg",
    "3":"Next.png"
  }
}
```

with 
.update({ username: "Oran.Hammes" },{$set: {"Documents" :{"4": "newpicture.png"}}})

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongo has the `$set` part of its update command for updating values within a single document. You can read more about modifying documents here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/

An example would be:

```
db.users.update(
    { "username": "Oran.Hammes" },
    {
        $set: {
            "Documents.4" : "newpicture.png"
        }
    }
)
```

With regards to whether or not you will need to rewrite the data, refer to this question: [Does MongoDB $set write just the field or the whole document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374126/does-mongodb-set-write-just-the-field-or-the-whole-document) . Basically, this depends on how you setup your database, and how much memory is allocated to each document.

Comment: db.users.update({ username: "Oran.Hammes" },{$set: {"Documents.4" : "newpicture.png"}}). I get no error, but the data does not change.

Comment: db.users.update({ "username": "Oran.Hammes" },{$set: { "Documents.4": "newimage.jpg"}}); Worked

Comment: ahh sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 2):

you can use db.collection.update:

```
db.users.update(
    { "username": "Oran.Hammes" },
    $set: { "Documents.4": "newimage.jpg" } });
```

the first curly is filter to get reference your record(called document in MongoDB), and then you only add new item(s) to your record.
Hope this helps.

Comment: if username is unique in your collection, it's ok, but better way to reference your record using its _id of course.

Comment: This will not work, as **whole** document will be replaced by `{ "Document": { "4": "newimage.jpg" } }`

Comment: right, i forgot to add $set, thx for the warning, i edit my answer

Comment: db.users.update({username: "Oran.Hammes" },$set: {Documents: { "4": "newimage.jpg" } });
Thu Dec 31 21:44:57.930 SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: Changed to .update({ username: "Oran.Hammes" },{$set: {"Documents" :{"4": "newpicture.png"}}})
No error but data does not change

Comment: Still it will replace `"Documents":{
    "1":"image.png",
    "2":"Test.jpg",
    "3":"Next.png"
  }` with `"Documents":{
    "4": "newimage.jpg"
  }`
  
  @matt-way answer will work

Comment: addes  "Documents" : {
  "4" : "newpicture.png"
 },
 as its own feild

Comment: db.stack.update({ "username": "Oran.Hammes" },{$set: { "Documents".$.4": "newimage.jpg"}});
... 
... 
Leaves just dots

Comment: No data changed. Want a pic?

Comment: Tried this as well.  db.stack.update({ "username": "Oran.Hammes" },{$set: { "Documents.$.4": "newimage.jpg"}});
Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array.

Comment: now try pls, this should make it, I checked locally in my machine

Comment: Yeah i tried matt ways db.stack.update({ "username": "Oran.Hammes" },{$set: { "Documents.4": "newimage.jpg"}}); worked. Thanks for helping

Comment: np, i didn't use mongo in shell for a while, it looks i'm rusted!

Comment: Yeah i tried his, the only thing wront was the "username", once i saw ur comment about the Documents$4, i gave his another try and it worked. Once again, thanks i appetite the help alot!